# How to get selected text from dynamic element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi all my aim is to get selected content of editable dynamic div

below is my code

```js
function getSelectionHtml() {
  var html = "";

  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var sel = window.getSelection();

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      var container = document.createElement("div");

      for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
        container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
      }

      html = container.innerHTML;
    }
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
    if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
      html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
  }
  
  alert({
    title: "Copied Text",
    text: '"' + html + '"',
    timer: 10000
  });
}

// The alert() function is disabled in Stack Snippets.
function alert(opts){swal($.extend({type:"info",confirmButtonText:"Close"},opts));}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="myarea" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<button onclick="getSelectionHtml();">Get HTML</button>
```

Above code is working fine if text is present on page load. But when i dynamically append div to  main div. Selecting text over there doesn't getting the text

Comment: If you are setting event using inline script (what you shouldn't do...), it should work. Provide MCVE. EDIT: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/qehmp5pq/

Comment: @wolff : check this once http://jsfiddle.net/nickle72000/sn7poyx4/2/

Comment: Is it what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/sn7poyx4/4/  Using mousedown instead of click because using click, selection is lost

Comment: @wolf thanks its working